# how to inport 127.0.0.1.sql file to localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I reinstall wamp server on My windows. Before installing wamp, I was exported My localhost full database as 127_0_0_1.sql. But now I need to re-import My localhost sql file to the phpmyadmin after intalling wamp. Then how can I do it?

Comment: no any idea about this matter?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/import-database-using-phpmyadmin

> 1. Open phpMyAdmin by clicking the phpMyAdmin icon
> 2. Create or select the database
>
>    - Select the database in
>        the left menu that you will be working with 
>        *or*
>    - Create an empty database and use that
> 3. Click Import in the top
>      menu
> 4. Under File to Import, click Browse and select the backup file you
>      previously created (it will be either a .sql .zip or .tar.gz file).
> 5. Click Go at the bottom right

Comment: actually I have not specific database. because now I have fresh phpadmin and I have exported all databases of the old phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Hema Create an empty new database for each old database and then import to each one. I have updated the answer.